# Cubic convergence of itearative method

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

thank you for your time at first!

It's my homework, so I don't expect answer with result, only some hint.

With given iteration method
$$x_{n+1} =  \frac{x_n(x_n^2 + 3U)}{3x_n^2 + U} $$
show cubic convergence to $\sqrt U$

My first consider is lack of $x_0$ or $x_1$ (I will assume that $x_1$ is the base ), which would make this task much easier.

I've stared by induction:
for $ n = 1 $ and divide by $x_1^3$:

$$\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}^3} = \frac{x_1^2 + 3U}{x_1^2(3x_1^2 + U)} = ???$$

I can't move from this point. 
Thanks for hints!

Comment: when $n\to\infty$,the equation $x_{n+1} =  \frac{x_n(x_n^2 + 3U)}{3x_n^2 + U}$ becomes $x_{\infty} =  \frac{x_{\infty}(x_{\infty}^2 + 3U)}{3x_{\infty}^2 + U}$ or $\frac{(x_{\infty}^2 + 3U)}{3x_{\infty}^2 + U}=1$. The solution is $x_{\infty}=\sqrt{U}$

Answer (score 1):

Can you show that $$\frac{x_{n+1}-\sqrt{U}}{(x_n-\sqrt{U})^3}$$ converges?

Comment: Why we need to show that?

Comment: I think that's what cubic convergence means.  If you start with a good guess  then the next guess will have three times as many correct decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Think about Newton scheme which, for the solution of $f(x)=0$ gives as iteration process $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Since you have
$$x_{n+1} =  \frac{x_n(x_n^2 + 3U)}{3x_n^2 + U}$$ clearly $$f'(x_n)=3x_n^2+U$$ Search for $f(x_n)$.

Comment: This has been 6 years ago, but I would like to point out that I do not think this will work. I do not think Halleys method on $x^2-U$ is equivalent to applying Newtons method on some 
 other function $f$ (which you suggest is a cubic polynomial of the form $x^3+Ux+c$) that has $U$ as a root.